# Parse JSON string contents into PHP Array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse a string in JSON, but not sure how to go about this. This is an example of the string I am trying to parse into a PHP array.

```
$json = '{"id":1,"name":"foo","email":"foo@test.com"}';
```

Is there some library that can take the id, name, and email and put it into an array?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It can be done with [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/json_decode), be sure to set the second argument to `true` because you want an array rather than an object.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true); // decode json
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => foo
    [email] => foo@test.com
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$array = json_decode('{"id":1,"name":"foo","email":"foo@test.com"}', true);
//$array['id'] == 1
//$array['name'] == "foo"
//$array['email'] == "foo@test.com"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$obj=json_decode($json);  
echo $obj->id; //prints 1  
echo $obj->name; //prints foo
```

To put this an array just do something like this

```
$arr = array($obj->id, $obj->name, $obj->email);
```

Now you can use this like

```
$arr[0] // prints 1
```

Comment: Why not use the second parameter of `json_decode`? Now you lose the array keys, which seem to be quite usefull here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**json_decode()**](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '{"id":1,"name":"foo","email":"foo@test.com"}';  

$object = json_decode($json);

Output: 
    {#775 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"name": "foo"
      +"email": "foo@test.com"
    }
```

> *How to use:* **$object->id** //1

```
$array = json_decode($json, true /*[bool $assoc = false]*/);

Output:
    array:3 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "foo"
      "email" => "foo@test.com"
    ]
```

> *How to use:* **$array['id']** //1