# Sending a Multidimensional Array from Jquery to PHP. What I'm doing Wrong?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm having some trouble sending multidimensional array [N][N] from javascript to PHP, I already tried alot of solutions that I'd found here but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My JQuery code (saving values from a HTML table):

```
$rowArray = {};

for ($i = 0; $i < $myRows.length; $i++) {
    $row = $($myRows[$i]).find('td');
    $rowArray[$i] = {};
    for ($j = 0; $j < $row.length - 1; $j++) {
        $rowArray[$i][$j] = $($row[$j]).html();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
$myJsonString = JSON.stringify($rowArray);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"../../download/myStore.php",
    data: { table: $myJsonString },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

PHP Side:

```
echo $_POST['table']; //just to see what is coming, but i want to work as array

//$data = json_decode($_POST['table'],true); -> when I echo $data, the output is an error Array to String conversion
```

Output:

```
{"0":{"0":"Cadastrado em","1":"Data da Venda","2":"Empreendimento","3":"Bloco/<br>Unidade","4":"Cliente/<br>Parceiro","5":"Valor","6":"Filial","7":"Gerente","8":"Corretor","9":"Veículo"},"1":{"0":"27/04/2016","1":"11/04/2016","2":"Villa Flora Hortolândia - Cond. 06","3":"Bloco/Torre: 13, Unidade: 283","4":"Lidiane Sasaki Santana","5":"20.664.259","6":"Campinas","7":"NATAL","8":"WILLIAM PILOTO","9":"Internet"},"2":{"0":"12/04/2016","1":"12/04/2016","2":"Lifespace Curitiba","3":"Bloco/Torre: 1, Unidade: 2404","4":"ANA","5":"351.000","6":"Curitiba","7":"André Barbosa de Lima","8":"Daniele","9":"Google"},"3":{"0":"12/04/2016","1":"12/04/2016","2":"ROSSI ATUAL MORADA","3":"Bloco/Torre: 3, Unidade: 407","4":"BERNADETE STARKE","5":"245.000","6":"Curitiba","7":"André Barbosa de Lima","8":"Dranka","9":"Google"},"4":{"0":"12/04/2016","1":"12/04/2016","2":"Lifespace Curitiba","3":"Bloco/Torre: 2, Unidade: 1105","4":"FLAVIA AMARAL","5":"272.500","6":"Curitiba","7":"André Barbosa de Lima","8":"Jesus","9":"Yahoo"},"5":{"0":"12/04/2016","1":"12/04/2016","2":"Lifespace Curitiba","3":"Bloco/Torre: 2, Unidade: 1809","4":"itajana","5":"270.500","6":"Curitiba","7":"André Barbosa de Lima","8":"Daniele","9":"Site Rossi"},"6":{"0":"27/04/2016","1":"14/04/2016","2":"Villa Flora Hortolândia - Cond. 05","3":"Bloco/Torre: 5, Unidade: 41","4":"Andre Fernando Da Silva Gradino","5":"184.303","6":"Campinas","7":"NATAL","8":"TIAGO","9":"Cadastro Manual"}}
```

How can I access each index inside each array to get my values?
Whenever I try to use an index like `$_POST['table'][0]` the output is just '{'.
Sorry for my english and sorry for this noob question, but I'm stucked here for hours and already tried alot of solution found here and on google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON string contents into PHP Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600024/parse-json-string-contents-into-php-array)

Answer (score 2):

As you already have inside your code (but commented out) you can use `json_decode($_POST['table'],true);` When you us this function you get a array, with 7 entrys (in this example).

Like this:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['table'], true);
```

The error occurs, because you `echo` the variable. Use `var_dump($data)` to see, that its really a array. `$data[0]`, `$data[1]`, ... holds then the data.

EDIT: Because you have nested array, you have to access the subarray again, like this:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['table'], true);
$var = $data[0][0]; // holds "Cadastrado em"
$var2 = $data[0][1]; // holds "Data da Venda"
```

I'm not sure, if this is intended, that you have an array in an array.

Comment: Omg, it works, sorry for the noob question, I was stucked for hours. Really Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use json_decode to transfrom the string literal into a PHP object.

```
 $json = '["apple","orange","banana","strawberry"]';
 $ar = json_decode($json);
 // access first element of $ar array
 echo $ar[0]; // apple
```

Answer (score -1):

Your commented line

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['table'],true);
```

is good, but you can't echo an array. This will fail:

```
echo $data;
```

This will work:

```
print_r($data);
```