# how to receive ajax response as array in php

Tags: php, json, ajax

I need to receive ajax response data as array in php. My jquery code in the view page and ajax response data come from CI function as `json_encode($data)`. I get in `alert(data)`. But how do I get this `json data` as array in my view page (same page) that I can extract the array with php. I googled very much but not found such type of solution. Whats the actual way to get ajax success data as variable in php page.

```
function client_deatails(){
  $data=$this->BillingModel->client_details_param($client_id, $company_id, $from, $to);
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

View page:

```
<?php
 if(!empty($data)){
   print_r($data);
 }
?>
```

jquery-ajax

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#client_id").focus();
            $(".param").change(function () {
                var dataString = {
                    client_id: $('#client_id').val(),
                    from: $('#fromDate').val(),
                    to: $('#toDate').val()
                };
                var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>billing/client_deatails",
                    data: {data: jsonString},
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        //$('#param-data').html(data);

                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("some error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Since JSON is the data type all you have to do is use it as such when returned.

Comment: how the question is duplicate? I just review it and he ask for success data pass back to extract with javascript. But I want to pass back the data in php@Jay Blanchard

Comment: Your description of the problem lead me to believe you needed to parse the AJAX when you got it back from PHP. I can dupe it with another answer if you'd like. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600024/parse-json-string-contents-into-php-array

Comment: "Whats the actual way to get ajax success data as variable in php page." PHp is no longer important at this point. You have to use the JSON you received from your PHP script in your current page. For this, since you're already using jQuery, you would take the data your received and place it in your page using jQuery.

Comment: yes of course, but I'm not expert in jQuery that's why I'm trying to pass it as PHP array then I can handle it easily.

Comment: It will not/can not be returned as a PHP array.because at this point you're dealing with the DOM.