# Grab value from JSON Array with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm pulling data from a table in my database.

When I run `var_dump($data)` I get the following:

```
string(250) "{
    "Name": "Bobby Banks",
    "Manager": "Barry Banks"
},"
```

I'd like to grab the `Manager` value.

I have tried `echo $data->Manager;` and `echo $data['Manager'];` but no success.

Comment: `$data = json_decode($data, true); echo $data['Name'];`

Comment: @ka_lin this should be an answer.

Comment: @DanielJames I pretty sure it's a duplicate and wanted to avoid downvotes :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON string contents into PHP Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600024/parse-json-string-contents-into-php-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:-

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($data, true);
echo $jsonObject['Manager'];
```

complete script:-

```
<?php

$stringJson = '{"Name": "Bobby Banks","Manager": "Barry Banks"}';
$json = json_decode($stringJson, true);

echo $json['Manager'];

?>
```

Output:-

```
Barry Banks
```

Comment: Hi @nandal - this doesn't output anything, sadly :-( Can you show me the full script you're using and I can see this?

Comment: Hi @michaelmcgurk, I have updated the answer, see if it helps in understanding php json object handling.

Comment: Thank You, @nandal - it was a trailing comma on my JSON that was giving me the problem all along.