# PHP Insert multiple records into mysql from one json string

Tags: php, mysql

```
$array = array(); 
foreach ($Addproduct_image as $row) { 
$array[] = '("' . mysql_real_escape_string($row["image"]) . '", ' . $row["color"] . ' , ' . $last_ID .')'; } 
$stmt1 = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO Product_img_col (image, color, pro_ID) VALUES '.implode(",", $array[])"); 
if ($stmt1->execute()) {return true;} else{return false;}

// Data to add.
{"name":"world","color":"world",($Default_Value)}]
```

I want to add this data into multiple rows. I think I will have to use implode function for multiple rows with a default value for third column "$default-value". I am not very good in PHP can anyone please help
.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: $array = array();
    
      foreach ($Addproduct_image as $row) {
       $array[] = '("' . mysql_real_escape_string($row["image"]) . '", ' . $row["color"] . ' , ' . $last_ID .')';
  }

      $stmt1 = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `Product_img_col`    (image, color, pro_ID) VALUES '.implode(",", $array[])");
  print_r($array);

  if ($stmt1->execute()) {return true;}
  else{return false;}                                    I tried this

Comment: @jerry Refering to your ealier comment on an awnser; we are not here to do your work. We simply help if it aint working or see how to fix it, but its not we do your work.

Comment: @Dorvalla Let me Re-edit my question I tried something which was not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON string contents into PHP Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600024/parse-json-string-contents-into-php-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to add all items to the query you will need to remove the [] from the `implode(",", $array[])` so it reads `implode(",", $array)`.

You could try adding `echo "INSERT INTO Product_img_col (image, color, pro_ID) VALUES '.implode(",", $array[])");` to your page so you have the query that you can test in phpMyAdmin or similar. This should help you debug.

Also if color is a string you should really put it inside quotes as you have done with image.

Answer (score -1):

- Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get a php array from your JSON.
- for each element in the array use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn it into JSON again, and then insert that as a single row

Comment: I need code as well. I am not very good in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$query = '';
$filename = "employee_data.json";
$data = file_get_contents($filename); //Read the JSON file in PHP
$array = json_decode($data, true); //Convert JSON String into PHP Array
foreach($array as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
{
      $query .= "INSERT INTO tbl_employee(name, gender, designation) VALUES ('".$row["name"]."', '".$row["gender"]."', '".$row["designation"]."'); ";  // Make Multiple Insert Query 
}

 if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query)) //Run Mutliple Insert Query
    {
         echo 'Imported JSON Data';
    }
```

**JSON_File - employee_data.json**

```
[  
       {  
         "name": "Michael Bruce",  
         "gender": "Male",  
         "designation": "System Architect"  
       },  
       {  
         "name": "Jennifer Winters",  
         "gender": "Female",  
         "designation": "Senior Programmer"  
       },  
       {  
         "name": "Donna Fox",  
         "gender": "Female",  
         "designation": "Office Manager"  
       }

     ]
```

For more details see the example in the below URL, It may help you

https://www.webslesson.info/2016/04/get-multiple-json-data-insert-into-mysql-database-in-php.html