# JSON remove unwanted characters

Tags: php, json

want to remove brackets and commas from my output it is a json data how can i do ??
 Mid term result of Sajid

```
[
    {
        "Englsih": "60"
    },
    {
        "Science": "55"
    },
    {
        "Arabic": "90.5"
    },
    {
        "Math": "60.3"
    }
]
```

Total marks =265.8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON string contents into PHP Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600024/parse-json-string-contents-into-php-array)

Comment: Decode it and use the array to your liking instead.

Comment: You can use `preg_replace('/[{},]+/', '', $string)` to remove any brackets and comma's from your json string. Are you sure that's what you want to do though? What's your end goal?

Comment: What do you mean by *Total marks =265.8*? You want to get sum of values or convert json to array?

Answer (score 0):

Make the string an array with json_decode and loop the array to sum the scores.

```
$sum=0;
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
foreach($arr as $class){
    foreach($class as $score) $sum += $score;

}
echo $sum; //265.8
```

https://3v4l.org/IXfcv

---

You can also use preg_match_all and array_sum.
Match all numbers and sum the output array

```
$str = preg_match_all("/[\d.]+/", $str, $m);
echo array_sum($m[0]); // 265.8
```

https://3v4l.org/RnbbB

Answer (score -1):

like these:

```
$json = '[
    {
        "Englsih": "60"
    },
    {
        "Science": "55"
    },
    {
        "Arabic": "90.5"
    },
    {
        "Math": "60.3"
    }
]';
$arr = json_decode($json);
$sum array_sum(arr);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. https://3v4l.org/BNAdO the array is multidimensional. Array_sum only works on flat arrays.